# How to optimize the isHealthy() method in OkHttp when the doExtensiveCheck parameter is set to true?

Tags: optimization, okhttp

We ues okhttp3.14.9 to send http requests in java project,and we found that put/post method took about 20ms while get just took 2ms,both requestbody is empty,anyone can help?

I found the root cause is the doExtensiveCheck parameter,so how to optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your OkHttp. This method is optimized in OkHttp 4.x and doesn’t have this performance problem.

Comment: The optimization works by only doing the socket check if the connection was idle longer than 10s. In practice this is a good trade-off between latency and not breaking on stale sockets.

Comment: Hi Jesse,thank you for your answer.I had tried the upgradation but found many versions inconsistency with my current project which may result in some uncertainty.Any other suggestions for version 3.x?

Comment: The OkHttp change log might help with the upgrade process. 3.x is dead!